# Java - how to create a file under unknown/variable path?

Tags: java, regex

I have a directory: `<dir>\Report\<env>\Log_XXX\Logs`
where **XXX** is randomly created at run time, so I have to create a file inside **Logs** folder.

Following is what I tried to generate the **Logs** folder:

```
new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Report/" + System.getProperty("env") + "/" + Pattern.compile("^Log_") + "/Logs").mkdirs();
```

Comment: Okay, and what is the issue? (please see [ask] and [mcve])

Comment: You can construct a File object pointing to D:\Report and then using get the Log_XXX folder underneath using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles() API.

Comment: It makes no sense to place a Pattern in a string concatenation.  Why not just `System.getProperty("env") + "/Logs"`?

Comment: @VGR : there is folder Logs_XXX which gets created during test run, where XXX is a timestamp

Comment: So… `System.getProperty("env") + "/Log_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "/Logs"`, then?

Comment: But Log_ folder will be already created using previous timestamp, which I don't have have knowledge of

Comment: It sounds like the question you meant to ask was: “How does one find the directory with the latest timestamp?”  Is that correct?

Comment: No “How does one create a file under directory whose suffix is dynamic?”

Comment: @Zabuza Issue is I want to create a file under a directory, of which I only know prefix i.e `Log_` while `XXX` part is unknown to me, Comprende?

Comment: So you’re just looking for any directory whose name starts with `Log_`?  If that is not the case, then how do you know which directory you want to create your file in?

Comment: @VGR, cuz at any time there will be only 1 directory whose name starts with `Log_`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, it appears you are trying to locate the one and only subdirectory whose base name starts with `Log_`.  You can accomplish this with [Files.list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#list%28java.nio.file.Path%29):

```
Path logParent = Paths.get(
    System.getProperty("user.dir"),
    "Report",
    System.getProperty("env"));

Path logDir;
try (Stream<Path> listing = Files.list(logParent)) {
    Optional<Path> match = listing.filter(p -> Files.isDirectory(p) &&
        p.getFilename().toString().startsWith("Log_")).findFirst();
    logDir = match.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(
        "No log directory found in " + logParent));
}
```